# Why are the cp values in plotcp() chart modified from the original table?

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree, rpart

What are the cp values on the rpart plotcp() chart?
I would expect these values to match the cp column in printcp(), but instead the following scale is calculated (from the plotcp code):

```
p.rpart <- x$cptable
cp0 <- p.rpart[, 1L]
cp <- sqrt(cp0 * c(Inf, cp0[-length(cp0)]))
```

So each cp value from the CV table is multiplied against the following one in the same column and then square rooted. Why?

Answer (score 1):

According to Uwe's answer, which can be found here:[Re: [R] Different cp values in rpart() using plotcp() and printcp()](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-February/303918.html)

**printcp() gives the minimal cp for which the pruning happens.

plotcp() plots against the geometric mean**

Actual relationship in the source code is provided below, where `cp0` is the *cp* value used in the printcp while `cp` is the *cp* value used in the plotcp.

```
cp0 <- p.rpart[, 1L]  
cp <- sqrt(cp0 * c(Inf, cp0[-length(cp0)]))
```